# Selenium adds skype click to call plugin by default

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am learning Selenium with Java web-driver and I have to implement test scripts for a web application.

Now when I run my test script, the Firefox browser opens and skype click to call plugin is already installed in that browser. And it causes some problems in UI of web page. For ex. it highlights all the digits(ex. 123 or 12-02-2013(date)) of web page by skype click to call.

This basically changes XPATHs or ids(I don't know exactly what it changes). But due to that my test conditions do not fulfill and my test fails.

Any help would be appreciable if I can remove that plugin from firefox.

NOTE: I do not have skype installed on my PC. Still that plugin is there by default.

Comment: did u try removing the plugin from firefox?

Comment: There is no way that Selenium is going to add in that plugin on it's own. It's installed on your machine, somewhere, so I'd suggest you disable it.

Comment: Actually I don't have installed skype click to call plugin in my Firefox.

Comment: I don't have skype installed on my PC. But when I reinstalled Firefox, I saw that firefox has a default add-on for Skype click to call. But it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Control Panel
- Uninstall "Skype Click to Call"
- Re-run your Selenium webdriver test